# Create MongoRepository restfull API within Spring MVC application

Tags: java, mongodb, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My background is in MSFT technologies and, perhaps, that's the reason I am struggling. What I am trying to do is create a restful MongoDb web API using spring-boot within Spring MVC application. I was able to expose MongoRepository implemented methods by adding application main class and running it through the command line with "mvn spring-boot:run". However, when attempting to host the app under JBoss, I am running into a number of problems.

Currently, I am trying to address the problem with servlet-context.xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.victar.kms" />
<mongo:repositories base-package="org.victar.kms.dal" />



<beans:bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="host" value="localhost" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="mongoTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</beans:bean>

<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="kms" host="localhost" port="27017" />
```

First of all, all online resources suggest that I should be using MongoFactoryBean, which is market as deprecated. Second, when I deploy the app, I get the following error:

```
15:12:29,082 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/kms-mvc]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 191) JBWEB000289: Servlet appServlet threw load() exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:64) [spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1419) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1409) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3593) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3802) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_92]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

I have structured my project to somewhat close to what I am used to:

the root package ("org.victar.kms") contains the MVC controllers
...dal contains repository implementations 
....models contains my entities or models

One of the repositories looks like this:

```
package org.victar.kms.dal;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.victar.kms.models.Subscription;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "subscriptions", path = "rest/subscriptions")
public interface SubscriptionRepository extends MongoRepository<Subscription, String> {

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.victar</groupId>
<artifactId>kms-mvc</artifactId>
<name>kms-mvc</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- When built in OpenShift the openshift profile will be used when invoking 
            mvn. -->
        <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
            will need. -->
        <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the deployments 
            folder. -->
        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>kms-mvc</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <!-- <plugin> <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> <version>2.4</version> 
                    <configuration> <outputDirectory>YOUR WAR DESTINATION</outputDirectory> <warName>ROOT</warName> 
                    </configuration> </plugin> -->
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

After spending a few hours researching, I went ahead and removed all of my configuration and application startup files as I felt I needed to minimize the complexity and understand the config file parsing issue. I would appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you.

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ kms ---
[INFO] org.victar.kms:kms:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:1.8.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.11.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.16:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.0.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.0.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:8.0.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.0.33:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:jar:2.4.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-core:jar:2.4.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.19.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.atteo:evo-inflector:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.github.fge:json-patch:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |        +- com.github.fge:jackson-coreutils:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- com.github.fge:msg-simple:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  \- com.github.fge:btf:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:jar:1.3.5.RELEASE:compile
```

EDIT:

Updated pom.xml to:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.victar</groupId>
    <artifactId>kms-mvc</artifactId>
    <name>kms-mvc</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>

            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>

        </dependency>


        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>

            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>

            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>

            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the openshift profile will be used when invoking 
                mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
                will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the deployments 
                folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>kms-mvc</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- <plugin> <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> <version>2.4</version> 
                        <configuration> <outputDirectory>YOUR WAR DESTINATION</outputDirectory> <warName>ROOT</warName> 
                        </configuration> </plugin> -->
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

That resolved the servlet-context.xml issue. New exception is likely related to bean configuration xml/class initialization:

```
17:22:24,409 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/kms-mvc]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 677) JBWEB000289: Servlet appServlet threw load() exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean definition
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:357) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:66) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) [spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
```

...

Comment: Your error is `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;` Which generally happens when there are multiple versions of same jars getting added to the deployable and the java classloader loading incompatible files

Comment: Spring boot generally pulls in a bunch of its dependencies, and your project has included its own version of spring jars.. I would advice deriving your module by making spring boot project as parent and the removing spring versions jars that you are adding

Comment: Shibashis, thanks for the prompt response. I've added the dependency tree to my original post. I apologize for my ignorance, but which packages need to be removed? I do see org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.11.4.RELEASE:compile, which does not match spring-data-commons-1.12.1.release.jar referenced in libraries.

Comment: You need to clean up your pom.xml. As per springboot documenation for 1.2.5 it is compatible with spring 4.1.6 https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/02/spring-boot-1-2-5-released

Comment: also you pom says springboot <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency> but your tress says 1.3.5.. so not sure where those jars are coming from

Comment: decompress the war file and check what jars are included in that

Comment: Thanks. What I've done so far was: 1) added parent that references 1.2.4.RELEASE of spring-boot-starter-parent and 2) added dependency management for spring-boot 1.2.5. Ultimately, downgrading from 1.3.5 (I've fixed jar mismatch prior to downgrading) seemed to get me beyond the xml config file issue. Now the new issue is JBWEB000289: Servlet appServlet threw load() exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean definition
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanClass, which is likely related to something I am missing. Thanks!

Comment: add the exception stacktrace to the question

Comment: Is that the complete stack trace? there seems to be no clue

Comment: It is. I do not have anything as @Autowired either.

Comment: mvn spring-boot:run. does that still work?

Comment: I removed spring app classes that start up the app. Now, after adding it back, I am back to config issues - cannot find entry point. Will take me a bit to figure it out...

Comment: What spring app classes did u remove?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113940/discussion-between-dennis-and-shibashis).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Shibashis I have fixed the problem. Indeed, it was an issue with multiple jars and jars with incorrect versions included in the project. The fix to this was rather simple - downgraded the project to the previous version of spring-boot and added dependency manager.

**pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.victar</groupId>
    <artifactId>kms-mvc</artifactId>
    <name>kms-mvc</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>

            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>

        </dependency>


        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>

            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>

            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>

            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                    <warName>ROOT</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The next problem was with **servlet-context.xml**. Downgrading to previous version of spring-boot resolved the warnings and errors related to MongoFactoryBean being marked as deprecated. While troubleshooting I've removed *class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean"* from the bean, which later caused a problem during bean initialization.

The resulting servlet-context.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.victar.kms" />
    <mongo:repositories base-package="org.victar.kms.dal" />

    <beans:bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean" >
        <beans:property name="host" value="localhost" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="mongoTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="kms" host="localhost" port="27017" />

</beans:beans>
```

Last but not least, my repositories were using relative path notation, which is not supported by Spring. That is, *@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "keys", path = "api/keys")* will not work. I had two options - either to rename *api/keys* to, say, api-keys or to use *application.properties* file to override *spring.data.rest.base-path* with my base URL. The application file below initializes my MongoDb repositories:

```
package org.victar.kms;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
     }
}
```

Again, special thanks to Shibashis for his invaluable contribution.